# What is the OleDb connection string for Access 2013?

Tags: database, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, connection-string, ms-access-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to create a Web application that connects to an Access 2013 database with following programming line:

```
string connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "data source=" + Page.Server.MapPath("App_Data\\db1.accdb");
```

But it failed to launch it due to the error

> Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not found in local machine

What is the correct connection string for Microsoft Access 2013?

Comment: Have you verified that `Page.Server.MapPath()` returns a valid path because otherwise this connection string seems fine. You can find connections strings [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com).

Comment: that is my database allocate i already verify

Comment: I made another edit to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The machine acting as the web server must have the "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010" installed. If that machine does not have Access installed on it then you can download the installer for the engine [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Note that the 64-bit installer includes the 64-bit version *only*; it does not include the 32-bit version (available separately on that same page).

**edit...**

As for the connection string, I just tested the following VBScript on my Access_2013 machine and it worked fine.

```
Option Explicit
Dim con, rst
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.Open "SELECT Col1 FROM Table1", con
Wscript.Echo rst(0).Value
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = nothing
```

I copied the connection string from [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007).

**edit...**

If you have access to the web server, you can check for the existence of the following two files:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL
```

On a 64-bit machine the first file indicates that the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine is installed. On a 32-bit machine it indicates that the 32-bit version is installed.

If the second (x86) file exists then you know that the 32-bit version of the Access Database Engine is present on a 64-bit machine.

**edit re: final comment**

The problem was indeed related to the "bitness" of the Access Database Engine:

> i install "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010" 64 bit i should install 32bit due to my visual studio is 32bit thanks for the advice

Comment: thanks for your reply but it doesn't work on it, it still pop up same error:
The "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" provider is not registered on the local machine
did you know what is the string connection for Microsoft Access 2013 ?

Comment: if my sources is like this:
string connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "data source=" + Page.Server.MapPath("App_Data\\db1.accdb");
// create a OleDbConnection object to connect to the database
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
i should change it to:

Comment: @user712063 I'm not so sure that your connection string is the problem. You said in one of your other comments that you have verified that `Page.Server.MapPath("App_Data\\db1.accdb")` is returning a valid path to the .accdb file. The only substantive difference between our connection strings is that mine had `Persist Security Info=False;` tacked on the end, and I don't think that omitting it would cause the error message you describe.

Comment: @user712063 I just noticed that your connection string does not have a trailing `;`. I know that it is not always required, but perhaps in this case its absence is messing things up. In fact, why not try just appending `;Persist Security Info=False;` to your existing connection string and see if that helps.

Comment: haiz....... i already add ;Persist Security Info=False;
still remain the same error:
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not found in local machine

Comment: problem solve, problem occur due to version of 
"Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010"
my microsoft office is 2013 64 bit and i install 
"Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010" 64 bit
i should install 32bit due to my visual studio is 32bit 
thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

It depends with the office you have installed, if you have x64 bit office then you must compile the application as a x64 to allow it to run, so if you want it to run on x36 then you must install office x86 to accept, i tried all the solutions above but none worked until when i realised i had office x64bit and so i built the application as x64 and worked.

I also realised that if you put it to any cpu but do not set to prefere 32 bit also works

Answer (score 0):

Let the provider to 12.0 it works for ACCESS 2013

just install these 2 elements:

1)Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358

then

2)microsoft access database engine 2007:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

PS: x86 for 32bits & x64 for 64bits.

Answer (score -1):

here use this

> provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0

this is the connection string for ms access 2013